# run cron every minute during a specific hour?

Tags: cron

Running a cron job every minute is easy, running it at specific minutes past the hour is easy.

But is it possible to say "only between 1300 and 1400 run every 1 minute"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes Like so

```
* 13 * * * <your command>
```

See http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Comment: That will (or would, since it has now been edited) run every minute between 1pm and 3pm

Comment: I know - Too quick on the post button. Corrected it though.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `*` for the minute specifier.

```
*      13       *       *       *      foo.sh
```

Comment: Quentin, you say @Ed Heal's answer will run every minute 1pm - 3pm, but your answer is the same.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Steve — That it has been edited since my comment (and within the "no history" grace period).

Comment: ;o)  no problems

Answer (score 0):

```
*/1      13       *       *       *      echo `date` > ~/cron.txt
```